# Bootstrap navbar goes behind embed tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the bootstrap navbar (v3.3.2) and the embed tag that I'm using to display a pdf loaded at runtime in an mvc5 application.
What happens is that when i click on a menu list item, in internet explorer it goes behind the embed, while in chrome or firefox it opens above (that's the correct behaviour).

The menu items are created using the standard bootstrap techniques http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

The cshtml file that opens the pdf file contains the following:

```
<div>
    <embed id="pdfContainer" src="@Url.Action("GetFile", new { file = Model.File, description = Model.Description })#view=fitH" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html" />
</div>
```

The GetFile method just returns a FileStreamResults.

How can i fix this issue?

**UPDATE** (code that reproduce the issue - copy/paste inside html file and change the DEMO.PDF at the bottom with a pdf on your local hard drive)

```
<html class=" js flexbox no-flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg no-smil svgclippaths">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PDF - PDF</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="backgroundBody">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PDFs ARCHIVE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Category <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Years <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2005</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1988</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content marginTop10">
        <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <embed id="pdfContainer" src="./demo.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 345px; background-color: red " wmode="transparent" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the properties for #pdfContainer. I'm assuming the z-index is set way too high.

Comment: there are no properties set to pdfContainer. I tried with z-index, but nothing happens in IE

Answer (score 0):

What are you embedding? Depending on the plugin required and how it works within the browser being used, sometimes the contents of the embed are rendered on *top* of the page, rather than *within* the page, if that makes any sense. In other words, the plugin content doesn't even exist within the scope of the document; it's just sort of plastered on top where it's supposed to show. If that's the case, there's really nothing that can be done about it.

Assuming a best case scenario, where you can affect this, the only tool in your arsenal is pretty much the CSS `z-index` property. Set the `z-index` menu to a ridiculously high value like `999999999999`, and see it that does anything at all (bear in mind that the element this is applied to must all either have `position:relative` or `position:absolute` or it won't do anything). If it goes over the embed, then you can back off to a more reasonable value that still places it over the embed. If it does nothing, then you're probably in the first scenario, and pretty much on an inclined plane wrapped helically around its axis. Any Big Bang Theory fans out there? ;)

Comment: It's hard to diagnose when we can't see a replicable example.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the Internet Explorer version(s) with this issue.
So I didn't bother testing the test case you added later on.

I've seen and fixed similar a few times before, for Internet Explorer up to and including v9. Version 10 and up is usually OK.
Here's an example (view source): [aix4admins.blogspot.com/](http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/)

If the issue only occurs in Internet Explorer up to and including v9, attempt to fix it with the following JavaScript.
It pushes the main content, your pdf, behind everything (`z-index: -1;`).
Or try with `z-index:0;` if your page's body has a `background-color` set and its `z-index: 0`.

The `position` property of the content container (`.container.body-content`) with the pdf, must be `relative` (or `absolute`).

Also you won't need the second fix (the CSS rule which sets the background colour) if your main content (the pdf) doesn't show through your dropdowns when they go over it.
So `var css = '.container.body-content {z-index: -1;}';` is probably OK.

**EDIT:** Insert just before the closing `body` element:

```
<script>
    if (typeof document.documentMode === 'number' // Internet Explorer?
        && typeof document.body.style.transition === 'undefined') { // Up to and including IE9.

        // Create a new <style></style> tag.
        var ie_style_fix = document.createElement('style');
        ie_style_fix.type = 'text/css';
        ie_style_fix.id = 'ie-fix1';

        // The 2 fixes.
        var css = '.container.body-content {z-index: -1;}' + '.navbar .nav.navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li {background-color: rgb(191, 1, 0);}';
        // Insert the 2 fixes into the new style tag.
        if (ie_style_fix.styleSheet) {
            ie_style_fix.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            ie_style_fix.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ie_style_fix);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it with IE11 on W7.I tried your code, but it doesn't work...if the pdf is missing due too a bad link i can see the menù, but when the pdf appears the menu goes behind it.

Comment: My JS will not work in any version of Internet Explorer later than IE9.

You need to completely remove the outer if statement.

Or change the outer if statement into:
`if (typeof document.documentMode === 'number) {' // Internet Explorer?`

Or, instead of the entire JS, add just the CSS line to your CSS, after the last rule for the `.body-content` class

`.container.body-content {z-index: -1;}`

And, if not already so, you must also add the CSS property `position: relative;` to the element with the `.body-content` class.


`.container.body-content {
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;
}`

Comment: The other thing that could sabotage this, is that the PDF file takes longer to load and then sets a higher `z-index`, overriding the one in the CSS file.
If that's the case, you'll need to do something similar to Desandro's [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Comment: To avoid this case (long loading time) I tried to set the z-index of the various divs with the browser inspector, but the result is always the same

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render the PDF directly into the browser from client-side javascript, rather than the `<object ...>` or `<embed ..>` tag. You can do this conditionally only for IE 9/10. It means also that you no longer require Acrobat plugin to be installed.